# Is the Hubble constant actually constant?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, space-expansion

For this question I completely understand the the constant is different over time, but just having one of those daydream thoughts and thought I'd ask.   As a layman, I've been made to believe the [Hubble constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law) is uniform across the universe. Being that the current explanation of gravity makes no sense to me, a thought crossed my mind.  Knowing that gravity is not a force as mass doesn't have an effect on it, and universes expand uniformly as far as I know.  Is it possible that this pseudo-force is a equal and opposite type solution.  And if so, has it/can it been tested if the mass of each galaxy influences a neighboring systems apparent acceleration?

Comment: Are you referring to constant in time (at a given place) or constant for different redshifts, or constant when inferred from measurements in different directions?

Answer (score 1):

> "Knowing that gravity is not a force as mass doesn't have an effect on
> it, and universes expand uniformly as far as I know. Is it possible
> that this psuedo-force is a equal and opposite type solution."

Honestly, these first two sentences are confusing, but both sound incorrect. In the theory of general relativity (Einstein's theory of gravity which subsumes Newton's), mass effects gravity and gravity effects mass. When applied to models of cosmology, the expansion of a model of the Universe's cosmological evolution is not necessarily uniform in time - it is often quantitatively described by the [scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)).

More generally, it is called the [Hubble parameter](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Astro/hubble.html) because it is not constant, rather it is a function of cosmological redshift, $H(z)$. Hubble's law is the equation you're probably referring to, which relates the recessional velocity of an object as viewed from Earth to its distance from Earth, and which is true for a constant Hubble parameter (i.e., the local Hubble parameter is approximately constant). On very large cosmological scales, the [Cosmological Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle) essentially states that the Universe is homogeneous and isotropic, which would imply that the Hubble parameter is constant across the Universe. This principle is not completely proven observationally, but it [seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_principle#Observations) mostly true (as far as we can tell).

Also, I do not understand what force you're referring to. If you're referring to the cosmological expansion of space, the underlying cause of this is not well understood (the acceleration of this expansion has been observed and is often identified as being due to "dark energy"), this happens across cosmological scales and does not effect physics within a galaxy.